# Como posso desfazer esses 3 commits?

Tags: git, github, commit

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

$ git status
Refresh index: 100% (16/16), done.
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

```
    modified:   Blender/web/Aquario-concreto.html
    modified:   Blender/web/Aquario.html
    modified:   Blender/web/Banheiros.html
    modified:   Blender/web/Jaula-arame.html
    modified:   Blender/web/Jaula-oncas.html
    modified:   Blender/web/Jaula-porta-metal-grade.html
    modified:   Blender/web/Portaria.html
    modified:   Blender/web/Refeitorio.html
    modified:   "Blender/web/Zool\303\263gico.html"
    modified:   Blender/web/casa-lembrancas.html
    modified:   Blender/web/jaula-flamingos.html
    modified:   Blender/web/jaula-leao.html
    modified:   Blender/web/jaula-passaro-guara.html
```

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
    Blender/web/Lago-cisnes.html
    Blender/web/jaula-aves-lado-aramado.html
    Blender/web/jaula-aves.html
    Blender/web/jaula-babuino.html
    Blender/web/jaula-camelo.html
    Blender/web/jaula-cangurus.html
    Blender/web/jaula-grupo passaros.html
    Blender/web/jaula-pinguins.html
    Blender/web/jaula-repteis.html
    Blender/web/jaula-suricates.html
```

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de dar o comando recomendo que faça um backup da pasta com o seu projeto. Toda a pasta incluindo arquivos do .git/

```
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

Ou, para ser mais exato, você pode voltar para um determinado commit:
Dê um:

`git log`

Agora é só pegar o id do commit que você quer voltar para e dar o seguinte comando, substituindo o ID pelo id do seu commit

```
git reset --hard ID
```

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Estou tendo que subir os aquivos do TCC em commits separados pra não ultrapassar o tamanho máximo permitido pelo GIT (50MB por commit).

Comment: se deu certo, marca a resposta como aceita ou útil. Obrigado. Qualquer coisa tô a disposição.